# How do I use grep to extract a single word from a string using positive lookbehind and lookahead?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a string literal stored in a variable.

```
fullString="Line 1 Line 2 captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha poting Line 3"
```

I only want to extract the word `poting` from this string. If I echo the string and pipe the result through a grep as follows:

```
echo $fullString | grep "captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha"
```

I am returned the entire line again in the stdout.

```
Line 1 Line 2 captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha poting Line 3
```

If I use -o option as following

```
echo $fullString | grep -o "captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha"
```

I am returned only the part I had supplied as argument to the -o option

```
captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha
```

I want to extract only the word `poting` which comes after `captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha`  and is succeeded by other characters  `Line 3`. How do I use grep to achieve a positive lookbehind and lookahead and extract only `poting`?

Comment: Use awk or sed with a regex.

Comment: Is that word always coming in same position or position of that word in your input can be changed?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Same position, and the whole pattern `captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha poting` occurs only once. The input is not in the form of a file. It is a string literal and I do not want to echo the string and pipe the output to a file and perform sed or awk on that file. I want to be able to use that string literal without creating intermediate files.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed` solution:

```bash
fullString="Line 1 Line 2 captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha poting Line 3"
sed -E 's/.* captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha ([^ ]+).*/\1/' <<< "$fullString"

poting
```

Or this `gnu-grep` solution would also work:

```bash
grep -oP 'captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha \K\S+' <<< "$fullString"

poting
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. They are both fine. I was not aware of how to use the -P option on grep.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
echo "$fullString" | 
awk -v RS='captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha [^ ]*' '
RT{
  num=split(RT,arr,FS)
  print arr[num]
}'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `awk`'s `match` function in GNU `awk`'s array option for matches found in regex for capturing group.

```
echo "$fullString" | 
awk 'match($0,/captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha ([^ ]*)/,arr){print arr[1]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk ++NF OFS= FS='^.*captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha | .*$'
> gawk '$_ = $2' FS='^.*captcha_decode userEnteredCaptcha | .*$'
> ```

```
poting
```